# Test coverage overridden by other test

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-test

I am unit testing spring batch application.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={Reader.class, Writer.class, Job.class, Step.class})
public class MyTest {

@Autowired
private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

@Test
public void Test1(){
    //some mocking
    jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();
    //assertion etc. 
}

//This test is overridding code coverage of the first test. 
@Test
public void Test2(){
    //some mocking
    jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();
    //assertion etc. 
}
}
```

Why is this happening, anyone has any idea? What could be the reason?

Comment: What is code coverage in your case, and how do you measure it??

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Test coverage overridden by other test"? You have two different tests certainly with different setup/assertions. What is the issue exactly?

Comment: @borino Jacoco code coverage and sonarqube

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine We use Jacoco and sonarqube for code coverage. We use the same tool for all rest apis. It checks coverage of lines and branch coverage. In the first run, I do full end-to-end test for one condition, and in the 2nd run, I run the full end-to-end again to test the else statement, and that overrides the coverage of first test (the if statement). Anyway, I have resolved this issue by getting the bean thru applicationcontext and running the method manually. But still out of curiosity, why would this happen.

Comment: In regards to why would this happen, probably because the test coverage tool sees the exact same line of code (`jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();`) twice and hence overrides the coverage stats of the first one.. I'm not sure how these stats are calculated so I'm just guessing the reason. Anyway, glad you resolved your issue.

Comment: JazakAllah @MahmoudBenHassine

Comment: You are welcome! Always happy to help!